# How to stream XML output quickly from Python

Tags: python, xml, sax

What is a quick way of writing an XML file iteratively (i.e. without having the whole document in memory)? `xml.sax.saxutils.XMLGenerator` works but is slow, around 1MB/s on an I7 machine. Here is a [test case](https://gist.github.com/mgax/7088724).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realize that this question has been asked awhile ago, but, in the mean time, an `lxml` API has been introduced that looks promising in terms of addressing the problem: http://lxml.de/api.html ; specifically, refer to the following section: "Incremental XML generation".

I quickly tested it by streaming a 10M file just as in your benchmark, and it took a fraction of a second on my old laptop, which is by no means very scientific, but is quite in the same ballpark as your `generate_large_xml()` function.

Answer (score 3):

As [Yury V. Zaytsev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5132088/yury-v-zaytsev) mentioned, `lxml` realy provides API for generating XML documents in streaming manner

Here is working example:

```
from lxml import etree

fname = "streamed.xml"
with open(fname, "w") as f, etree.xmlfile(f) as xf:
    attribs = {"tag": "bagggg", "text": "att text", "published": "now"}
    with xf.element("root", attribs):
        xf.write("root text\n")
        for i in xrange(10):
            rec = etree.Element("record", id=str(i))
            rec.text = "record text data"
            xf.write(rec)
```

Resulting XML looks like this (the content reformatted from one-line XML doc):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root text="att text" tag="bagggg" published="now">root text
    <record id="0">record text data</record>
    <record id="1">record text data</record>
    <record id="2">record text data</record>
    <record id="3">record text data</record>
    <record id="4">record text data</record>
    <record id="5">record text data</record>
    <record id="6">record text data</record>
    <record id="7">record text data</record>
    <record id="8">record text data</record>
    <record id="9">record text data</record>
</root>
```

Comment: In order to make this work under python 3 I had to change "w" to "wb" and xrange to range.